# Emacs "Tramp" sudo setup in authinfo.gpg : machine specific sudo accreditation

Tags: emacs, sudo, tramp

I have a bookmark for a remote file over ssh thus:

/ssh:remoteuser@remote-server|sudo:remoteuser:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

After much messing around this entry in my authinfo.gpg file allowed tramp toprovide the sudo password for "remoteuser" on the remote-server:

machine remoteuser port sudo login root  password remote-user-sudopassword

The problem I have is that this authinfo line isnt specific to remote-server : the host/machinename is in fact the remoteuser id. What does this mean? It means that the sudo password for "remoteuser" must be the same on all machines where remoteuser operates. Is there some alias/mapping i can do in auth-sources/tramp to enable me to have different authinfo lines for tramp sudo accreditation for "remoteuser"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your remote file name is wrong. It must be

```
/ssh:remoteuser@remote-server|sudo:remote-server:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

That is, the host name in both parts of the file name must be the same. This would change your `.authinfo.gpg` entry to

```
machine remote-server port sudo login root password remote-user-sudopassword
```

Note, that in the upcoming Emacs 27.1 (containing Tramp 2.4) it will be checked that the host names in such a multi-hop match.

Comment: Hi Michael, interestingly enough I modified that after posting but it did work. Is that down to partial matching?  (my user was, for example "xyz" and the host name was "xyz-server").

Comment: Yes, it is a regexp match. Hmm, Tramp cannot check such a case ... it's always possible to fool it out :-)

Comment: But just to clarify in the next Tramp you mentioned there will be a way to have an authinfo line for remote-server and remote-user as two unique identifiers for a single line? (it strikes me that if sudo is set up correctly on the remote machine then "login" should be remote-user so we are not sudoing to root but just a normal user sudo - if that makes sense).

Comment: Sue, shall be possible. It would be something like `machine remote-server port sudo login remote-user password remote-user-sudopassword`.

Comment: And, btw, in Emacs 27 there is also the new feature that Tramp saves the proper `.authinfo.gpg` line if you have entered a new password.